# Failed to Connect to MySQL at localhost:3306 with user root

Tags: mysql

I use Mysql Workbench to connect my database,[[image: Hostname Port and Username are as shown in figure ,and password is right[1]]

Hostname Port and Username are as shown in figure ,and password is right.When I click Test Connection ,it show as above.But if i use 3307 in place of 3306 as port,it connect sucessfully. What matter lead that and how I fix it?

I use macbook pro and I don't know check which my.cnf. I use sudo vim /usr/local/mysql/my.cnf in terminal .
And the my.cnf is as below:

```
[mysqld] 
 sql_mode=NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES
```

And I rewite it as below:

```
[client]
port=3306
socket=/tmp/mysql.sock

[mysqld]
port=3306
socket=/tmp/mysql.sock
key_buffer_size=16M
max_allowed_packet=8M 
[mysqldump]
quick
```

But it does not work.

Comment: Is your your `mysql` running on `3307` or `3306` port???

Comment: please check your mysql configuration `my.cnf` the port should be `port=3306` [https://dev.mysql.com/](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/option-files.html)

Comment: @DarshanPatel yes, it is running

Comment: but on which port??? check my.cnf as @ichadhr suggested

Comment: @ichadhr I use macbook pro and I don't know check which my.cnf. I use sudo vim /usr/local/mysql/my.cnf in terminal .                                                   And the my.cnf is as below:                                                                                    [mysqld] sql_mode=NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES           And I rewite it as below:                                                                     [client]
port=3306
socket=/tmp/mysql.sock
  
[mysqld]
port=3306
socket=/tmp/mysql.sock
key_buffer_size=16M
max_allowed_packet=8M 
[mysqldump]
quick     But

Comment: @Sajad You must be kidding. That is the standard port for an HTTP server. This is a database.

Comment: @EJP but I use 3306 successfully before.

Comment: @shengfuzou you can specify the option file you have created by using the `--defaults-file` parameter. e.g `--defaults-file=[cnf path]` [dev.mysql](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/option-file-options.html)

Comment: @shengfuzou also make sure no other programs running on same port `netstat -lnp | grep 3306`

Comment: @shengpfuzou And what changed since? That's the question.

Comment: @EJP I forget， it is long ago.

Answer (score 44):

**Steps:**

1 - *Right click* on your task bar -->**Start Task Manager**

2 - *Click* on **Services** button (at bottom).

3 - Search for **MYSQL57**

4 - *Right Click* on MYSQL57 --> **Start**

Now again *start* your **mysql-cmd-prompt** or **MYSQL WorkBench**

Comment: mysql is not coming in services. What to do now?

Comment: which task bar?....

Comment: @Martian2049 THE Task bar. On Windows you can only have one Task bar.

Comment: @FireFuro99 To be fair, there are also various programs with their own task bars in them. So, to take away ambiguity, it probably should have said `Right click on the Windows Task Bar`.

Comment: @FireFuro99 The poster clearly said they were on a MacBook Pro.

Answer (score 8):

I had this exact problem after my last windows update and none of the above solutions worked. I know it's an old question, but if anyone has this problem in the future:

I managed to solve it by going to **windows control panel > administrative tools > Component Services and finding "MySQL57" in the Services(local) list** (I assume your server might have a slightly different name).

There I went to properties by right clicking and changed **the Startup Type to Automatic under the General tab**. Then I went on the **Log On tab and checked "Allow Service to interact with Desktop".**

If none of that works, you can try **checking the "This account" box and filling both password fields with the root password you set up after installing the server** (leave account blank).

I know it's a lot to do and most of these steps must be innefective, but I did it all at once and frankly have no clue which one solved the problem. Good luck I hope it helps.

Comment: This issue if its not your password. Is most certainly that the MySQL80 services is not running. So, that's the one that solves the issue. ...checkout out your services window and start service for MySQL80

Answer (score 7):

Open System Preference > MySQL > Initialize Database > Use Legacy Password Encription

Answer (score 6):

Try to execute below command in your terminal :

```
mysql -h localhost -P 3306 -u root -p
```

If you successfully connect to your database, then same thing has to happen with `Mysql Workbench`.

If you are unable to connect then I think `3306` port is acquired by another process.

Find which process running on `3306` port. If required, give admin privileges using `sudo`.

```
netstat -lnp | grep 3306
```

Kill/stop that process and restart your MySQL server. You are good to go.

---

Execute below command to find `my.cnf` file in macbook.

```
mysql --help | grep cnf
```

You can change `MySQL` port to any available port in your system. But after that, make sure you restart `MySQL` server.

Comment: I use your command and show as below :                                                              `    order of preference, my.cnf, $MYSQL_TCP_PORT,
     /etc/my.cnf /etc/mysql/my.cnf /usr/local/mysql/etc/my.cnf ~/.my.cnf  `          I check the four file ,and all then are empty.Why and what to do for me?

Comment: I use                                                                                                               mysql -h localhost -P 3306 -u root -p                                                                to connect , but it show                                                                               Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)                                                                                                                   I use   mysql --help | grep cnf                           it show nothing.

Comment: then use `netstat` commnad to find out which process is running for port `3306` and also execute `mysql -h localhost -P 3307 -u root -p`. If you got success with 3307 then your MySQL server is running on 3307 port.

Comment: This works well on PC, but the command is : 

netstat -a -n -o 

... on the command line (you may need admin privs) ...

and then take the PID from the last column and look it up on the details pane of Task Manager (CTL+SHIFT+ESC)

I was able to determine that yes, MySql is on that port ... 

Sadly, that doesn't mean that I actually solved the problem, but it's a great diagnostic step. 

++

Comment: This worked for CLI but I still can't connect in workbench. What might my issue be?

Comment: Check port is open or not if you are using AWS. Another possible configuration you might check similar to this https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-allow-remote-access-to-mysql

Answer (score 3):

It worked for me this way:

Step1: Open System Preference > MySQL > Initialize Database.

Step2: Put password you used while installing MySQL.

Step3: Start MySQL server.

Step4: Come back to MySQL Workbench and double connect/ create a new one.

Answer (score 2):

[image: Go to system preferences, then "MySQL"]

[image: Click on "Start MySQL Server"]

Go to system preferences, then "MySQL".
Click on "Start MySQL Server".

Answer (score 2):

On window, work for me.

1 - Open **"Service"**

2 - Search for **MYSQL**

3 - Right Click on **MYSQL80 --> Start**

**Hope it work in your MySQL Workbench**

Thank you!!!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

MySQL default port is 3306 but it may be unavailable for some reasons, try to restart your machine. Also sesrch for your MySQL configuration file (should be called "my.cnf") and check if the used port is 3306 or 3307, if is 3307 you can change it to 3306 and then reboot your MySQL server.

Answer (score 1):

Go to >system preferences >mysql >initialize database

-Change password
-Click use legacy password
-Click start sql server

it should work now

Answer (score 1):

I re-downloaded many times and found out it's so simple!

**THERE ARE TWO DOWNLOADS NEEDED**

**1. SQL Community Server**
https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/
*This is what shows up in "System Preferences" and allows you to start the instance!*

**2. MYSQL Workbench**
https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/
*This is what you're trying to fix.. Once the Instance is on you can successfully connect* :)

(for macOS system users)

Answer (score 0):

At rigth side in Navigator -> Instance-> Click on  Startup/Shutdown -> Click on Start Server

It will work surely

Answer (score 0):

1. go to apple icon on the top left corn and click "System Preference"
2. find "Mysql" at the bottom and click it
3. "start Mysql server"

Answer (score 0):

It failed because there is no server install on your computer. You need to Download 'MySQL Community Server 8.0.17' & restart your server.

Answer (score 0):

1. set root user to mysql_native_password

$ sudo mysql -u root -p # I had to use "sudo" since is new installation

mysql:~ `USE mysql`;
mysql:~ `SELECT User, Host, plugin FROM mysql.user;`
mysql:~ `UPDATE user SET plugin='mysql_native_password' WHERE User='root';`
mysql:~ `FLUSH PRIVILEGES;`
mysql:~ `exit;`

$ `service mysql restart`

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem on MACOS. I did the following. Make sure MySQL Server is installed.

1. Command + Space -> Type mysql. Open the option mysql.prefPane
2. Click on the button Stop MySQL Server. Let the server stop.
3. Click on Initialize Database button
4. A new Popup will open. Type the password you want for root user.
5. Once the password is long enough, OK button will get enabled. Click on OK button
6. Do Test Connection from MySQL WorkBench and enter the password you set in above step. It should work.

Answer (score 0):

For those of you getting this on an SQL Server container on docker, when you do the run command, be sure you put `-p 3306:3306` so for example, my run command looks like `docker run --name test-mysql -p 3306:3306 -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=your_password -d mysql`

Answer (score -1):

in `my.ini` check option `skip-networking` under `[mysqld]`. It should be off.

```
[mysqld]
skip-networking = OFF
```

Comment: see: https://superuser.com/questions/578678/mysql-cant-turn-off-skip-networking.   The `= OFF` is not needed, this is default and `skip-networking` is also not needed because default this option is disabled (see: [skip-networking](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_skip_networking) )

Comment: When I install maria db I turned off this feature and got this problem. When I look in doc - I found this valiarble and after look in my ini and found it with ON value.

Comment: The linke `skip-networking` does not need not exist, when you need network access to MySQL.  There is only a need for adding `skip-networking` when you set it to `ON` (or `1`)