# Trying to connect to a mySQL db on Amazon AWS using mySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, ssl, ssh

I just opened an account on Amazon AWS. In this account, I created a mysql database instance, that I am now trying to connect to on my home computer use mySQL Workbench. I have entered the database endpoint (as listed in my account) and added the user name I set up for the master username for the database. When I hit "test connection" (using standard TCP/IP connection) however, I get a "Failed to connect..." message. I have a feeling that the problem may be that I need to use SSL and/or SSH. But I am a neophyte here, and I don't know how to properly set this up or configure mySQL Workbench with this. I am seeking assistance

Comment: What's the rest of the error (including any numbers or codes)?  Also, when you say "MySQL instance," are you referring to an RDS/MySQL database instance, or something else?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot there was no error code. This was purely a failure to connect to the DB issue. 2nd, yes, this is was an RDS/MySQL database instance

Comment: I really hope they haven't changed workbench to the point that it no longer shows the code... See [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32022580/1695906), where the code in parentheses is 61.  Please check this, and also mention the OS of your desktop machine, since the codes vary by OS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there that my database instance was misconfigured somehow, though not as JERRY suggests. I created a new MySQL DB instance and was able to connect to that without needing any other special configuration changes. So I am now using the new instance, and have deleted the old one. I wish I could provide more insight into what the problem with the first DB was, but the insight I have is (as I said) after I created the 2nd DB instance, no other configuration was necessary

Answer (score 0):

You need to allow your mysql server to the user my user policy.
You can allow your Public IP address.

Please refer below case:
[Cannot ping AWS EC2 instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21981796/cannot-ping-aws-ec2-instance)

Comment: I appreciate your suggestion. However it did not solve my issue. Thank you though!