# Unable to connect to 127.0.0.1:3306 in Mysql

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, mysql-error-1064

I was creating a very large table using a python data set in the Mysql server, which I today realized was beyond the server's capacity.

Post which I am unable to connect to the server

I get the following error when I try to establish a connection on the MySQL workbench, I also get something similar when I try the same on python using MySQL connector 
Following is a screenshot of the error

[image]

I tried setting up a new connection as follows, but I receive the same error:

[image]
I tried this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32022580/failed-to-connect-to-mysql-at-localhost3306-with-user-root), which is similar but I keep getting the following error

```
'mysql' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Is there any other way I can connect, or if there is anything I have to do before I can connect?

Comment: If you want to use mysql from command prompt, add it [to your path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5920136/mysql-is-not-recognised-as-an-internal-or-external-command-operable-program-or-b)

Comment: How are you "pushing"? What are the answers to the question that was put in the dialog box for you? What does the mysql server error log say?

Comment: @danblack Sorry, I meant creating a new table. I've appropriate changes

Comment: The most likely causes are the two first listed in the Workbench error message. `127.0.0.1` is your own machine, it's easy to verify if it's running or not.

Comment: MySQL isn't running in this host. Try connecting to the host where it *is* running.

Comment: data can be loaded in multiple SQL ways, which do you use? What table structure (`SHOW CREATE TABLE {tablename}`)?  "beyond server capacity", so which capacity was exceeded? If you expect your mysql server to be running locally it isn't, check the error log, include it here if you don't follow it. Start the service should solve the connection issue. Also see [Bulk Data Loading for InnoDB Tables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/optimizing-innodb-bulk-data-loading.html)

Comment: @danblack If he can't connect to the server the table structure is irrelevant.

Answer (score -1):

127.0.0.1 this server not get . Try to reconnect in another address..